# Algorithm to find the 3 distinct largest of numbers in a continuous input?

Tags: java, algorithm

It works for distinct input but doesn't when some inputs match.
Im using the scanner class to take input. Im trying to write a code that checks for the case when either of the largest, secondlargest and thirdlargest variables are equal. The use of any data structure is not allowed.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Have a do while loop to input those 3 numbers. On the condition check if any number equals another number. If it does then ask for numbers again.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't handling the case when `largest == secondLargest` but `secondLargest != thirdLargest`.